# How do I make a target library available to my Java app?

Tags: java, jna

Using JNA, the documentation says:

> Make your target library available to your Java program. There are two ways to do this: The preferred method is to set the `jna.library.path` system property to the path to your target library. This property is similar to `java.library.path` but only applies to libraries loaded by JNA.

What does this actually mean? How do I  set the `jna.library.path` system property? My app needs to reference `Kernel32.dll`

Thanks

Comment: You say JNI, but the fragment you provided mentions JNA. These are two different options to use native libraries in Java.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set system properties by using the parameter "-D" when you invoke the Java Virtual Machine on the command line:

> `java -Djna.library.path=<path to your library> MainClass`

You can also set this programmatically in your code at your applications's startup when it has been read from e.g. a config file:

> ```
> System.setProperty("jna.library.path", <path to your library>);
> ```

I haven't used JNA myself, so I don't know if it is actually too late for the JVM when you set the value in code. In that case, go with the first option.

Comment: Thanks, can you just explain what does the 'MainClass' clause mean? Does that need to reference my application's entry point?

Comment: Yes, MainClass is the entry point, i.e. the class with the `main()` method.