# Using Tesseract In web project java

Tags: java, ocr, text-extraction, tess4j

I am using tess4j for the OCR. Basically Tesseract is developed in C++ . When I use it in Web Project of java it is giving errors because it needs dll files because tess4j uses JNI. So I wanted to ask can we use Tess4j in web projects . If yes then how?and IF NO then alternatives?

Comment: seems that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370545/how-do-i-make-a-target-library-available-to-my-java-app can help

Comment: that didn't help much

Comment: The DLLs are embedded in `tess4j.jar` and will be extracted to system temp folder and loaded from there.