# Specified module could not being found loading DLL in JNA

Tags: java, jna

I have this class initialiser:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\Users\\lucas\\Desktop\\libraries");
System.loadLibrary("libTTARCHHelper");
TTARCH_LIBRARY=(TtarchLibrary)Native.loadLibrary(TtarchLibrary.class);
```

And the DLL is located at `C:\\Users\\lucas\\Desktop\\libraries\\libTTARCHHelper.dll`

If I run this in Eclipse I get 'The specified module could not be found' and if I run it as a JAR I get 'no libTTARCHHelper in java.library.path'.

How do I fix these? I even tried putting the DLL in a folder in the PATH environment variable.

Full debug using the file direct load:

```
Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.Native extractFromResourcePath
INFO: Looking in classpath from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@c387f44 for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.Native extractFromResourcePath
INFO: Found library resource at jar:file:/C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/My%20Stuff/Eclipse%20Workspaces/Build%20Paths/jna-5.6.0.jar!/com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.Native extractFromResourcePath
INFO: Extracting library to C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-103324076\jna5931694657592960137.dll
Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary loadLibrary
INFO: Looking for library 'C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\libraries\libTTARCHHelper.dll'
Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary loadLibrary
INFO: Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary loadLibrary
INFO: Trying C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\libraries\libTTARCHHelper.dll
Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary loadLibrary
INFO: Loading failed with message: The specified module could not be found.

Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary loadLibrary
INFO: Adding system paths: []
Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary loadLibrary
INFO: Trying C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\libraries\libTTARCHHelper.dll
Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary loadLibrary
INFO: Loading failed with message: The specified module could not be found.

Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.Native extractFromResourcePath
INFO: Looking in classpath from jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@c387f44 for C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\libraries\libTTARCHHelper.dll
Aug 26, 2020 12:28:51 AM com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary loadLibrary
INFO: Loading failed with message: Native library (win32-x86-64/C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\libraries\libTTARCHHelper.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Users\lucas\eclipse-workspace\TEST\bin;C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\My Stuff\Eclipse Workspaces\Build Paths\jna-5.6.0.jar)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\libraries\libTTARCHHelper.dll':
The specified module could not be found.

The specified module could not be found.
```

The rest of the trace:

```
Native library (win32-x86-64/C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\libraries\libTTARCHHelper.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Users\lucas\eclipse-workspace\TEST\bin;C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\My Stuff\Eclipse Workspaces\Build Paths\jna-5.6.0.jar)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:301)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:461)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:192)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:646)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:630)
    at com.test.TTARCHHelper.<clinit>(TTARCHHelper.java:17)
    at com.test.main.main(main.java:6)
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:191)
        ... 6 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:204)
        ... 6 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Native library (win32-x86-64/C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\libraries\libTTARCHHelper.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Users\lucas\eclipse-workspace\TEST\bin;C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\My Stuff\Eclipse Workspaces\Build Paths\jna-5.6.0.jar)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.extractFromResourcePath(Native.java:1095)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:275)
        ... 6 more
```

So it looks like it doesnt find it , It throws a

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.
```

I found the problem, the DLLs were for the wrong bit. Eclipse runs on 64 and the JAR uses the 32bit JVM. I downloaded the 32 bit dlls too and now it works when I run the JAR. However the 64 bit dlls in Eclipse keep throwing the module exception above

Comment: You're probably going to have to package the DLL with your Java application.  Create a resources folder, and include the folder in your classpath.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a target library available to my Java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370545/how-do-i-make-a-target-library-available-to-my-java-app)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I  tried packaging the DLL into the jar. Im getting this error, 'Native library (libTTARCHHelper) not found in resource path ([file:/C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/out.jar])' however the libTTARCHHelper.dll is in the out.jar file root. What is happening?

Comment: Also, there should be several layers of suppressed exceptions in the stack trace.  Can you post the error message in the first line of each portion of the stack trace (the entire trace isn't necessary, just that last exception/error message).

Comment: Done, see above I think the problem is im getting 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNA will look for libraries at locations in the `jna.library.path` environment variable.

One option is to specify it as a command line option in Eclipse's run configuration.  In the Run menu, select Run Configuration. Go to the (x)=Arguments tab.  Add this in the VM arguments field:

`-Djna.library.path=C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\libraries`

You can also programmatically set it in your code before attempting to load the DLL:

`System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\Users\\lucas\\Desktop\\libraries");`

As you later indicated with the debug log, it may be finding the DLL but failing to open it.  Possible reasons for this can be:

- The DLL is runtime-dependent on another DLL on your system that's not in the appropriate path(s). A common one is the Visual C++ Distributable.
  You may need to consult the DLL documentation for more information. You can sometimes use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from the SysInternals library to try to see what it's opening.
- Having a duplicate/incompatible version of a dependent DLL as above
- Running a 64-bit JVM and trying to open a DLL that's not 64-bit compatible, or vice-versa
- Your Java program may not have permission to read the directory where your library is located

To help diagnose the problem, look at the full stack trace.  While the most recent error message may not be relevant (file not found in a "backup" search) if you look down the trace you may see multiple suppressed exceptions from earlier attempts to open a DLL which may give you more informative debugging information.

Comment: Im still getting the error. It says java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library and also throws 'The specified module could not be found.' In both eclipse and the JAR i get 'Native library (win32-x86-64/libvorbis.dll) not found in resource path...'. I set the JNA system property

Comment: Have you tried using the full path of the file in the `Native.loadLibrary()` call?

Comment: I tried that, it says Native library (C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\libraries\libTTARCHHelper.dll) not found in resource path

Comment: Can you please turn on `DEBUG` logging for JNA and post the results on your question.

Comment: OK, so JNA is finding the library but failing to open it.  This could be for a few reasons, 32 bit vs. 64 bit, permissions, etc.

Comment: Looks like you were right, the dll was made for the wrong 32 or 64. It says when i run it from the JAR that its not a valid win32 application (how can I convert dll?) and when I run it in eclipse i get the module cannot be found error

Comment: You have to switch Eclipse to use a 32-bit JRE in its options.  You can specify this on a per-project basis.

Comment: Its not that I want eclipse to change, its more I want the 64 bit version to work. Whenever I load DLLs on a 64 bit JVM it says The specified module could not be found.
How do I fix this?

Comment: The problem is not Eclipse, it's the JRE you have for the project.  You have to use a 32-bit JRE to interact with the 32-bit DLL. Or you have to find a version of the DLL compiled for 64 bit to use with a 64-bit JRE.

Comment: You were right and I fixed it. The problems kept occuring because the DLLs required other ones which I had loaded but the names of the DLLs were not what the dlls internally depended on (?). It works now, however.

Comment: I do have one more question. I made a DLL and it requires the libstd++ dll (I used a dll depend viewer) and it wont load because it needs libstd++ to be loaded. How can I remove that dll from the depends or somehow include it in the dll without it needing the dll to be externally loaded?

Comment: Internal dependencies are a pain. I don't have that expertise, you should post a new question so someone else can answer.